# UDP discover broadcast and listen - not working for me

Tags: perl, udp, service-discovery

I have a simple device on my network that responds to udp broadcasts of a certain message.  It responds to the sender with location information.  I can send the broadcast and see the proper response coming in on Wireshark, but my perl code doesn't show the response.  I know this must be simple, but I cannot see it...

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

print "\n>> Discovery Program <<\n";
#--
#-- find.pl
#--

# Create a sending socket
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                       PeerPort  => 55555,
                       PeerAddr  => inet_ntoa(INADDR_BROADCAST),
                       Proto     => 'udp',
                       LocalPort => 0,
                       Broadcast => 1)
                   or die "Can't bind : $@\n";

# Send message
my $msg = "XYZ";
chomp $msg;
$sock->send($msg);

# Receive message
my $text;
$sock->recv($text,128);
print "\nReceived message '", $text,"'\n";
```

---

Comment: You should probably check the return value of `$sock->send` and `$sock->recv` for definedness and the error will be in `$!` if either method returns `undef`.

Comment: Does `recv` return?

Comment: recv does not return.